# MySQL INSERT/UPDATE without ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, insert

I may have either misunderstood how to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax, alternatively my database structure needs some work but here goes.

I have a table (bookings-meta) which represents meta data associated with another table (bookings) , different rows in the bookings table may or may not have specific meta data associated with them in the other table.

The bookings-meta table has the following columns, meta_id (primary key), booking_id, key and value.

From my understanding, to use ON DUPLICATE KEY I need to know what in this case is the meta_id, often this isn't the case, I'm trying to simply push a key, value pair to the table using the booking_id, so if the particular key exists then its replaced otherwise its inserted.

At the moment I have a seperate query to try to select the row, if its found then I UPDATE, if not then its an INSERT.

Is there a way of doing an insert/update in one query without using ON DUPLICATE KEY or have I missed a trick with this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If possible, I'd drop the `meta_id` column entirely and turn `booking_id` and `key` into a composite primary key. That'll save space in your table, allow use of `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, and be cleaner in general.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect, I don't know why but I kept on telling myself I needed that meta_id, on reflection its used nowhere!